# restful controllers in laravel

Tags: rest, laravel

I'm trying to implement a RESTful API using Laravel restful controllers ($restful = true in the controller). The problem is that I'd like to retrieve a single record by using /customer/123 instead of /customer/index/123 and I can't find a way to do this without implementing every route in route.php file.

Is there a way to map all /(model)/(id) to the appropriate controller and action ? (without doing one by one).

I'm using Route::controller() in the route.php file.

Comment: Laravel 4 drops in around a week. I suggest you look into it and resourceful controllers. Not the answer you want, but it's loads easier.

Comment: thank you, I'm following your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jason said, wait until L4 (may 28) or grab the beta from http://four.laravel.com and use the resourcecontrollers.

It is true that you must define every route, but I got some ideas for you:

- collect all your models via database or read and parse the files in the /models dir
- define (in a loop) all the routes to the models

In that way you can either use the L4 resourcecontroller or create a custom controller/route combo like your example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you have to route every controller. The automatic routing is instable and thus it is removed in laravel 4.